# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect with MZCroppableView rect issue

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am using this [library](https://github.com/mzeeshanid/MZCroppableView) to crop image form appropriate path.

Seems it works perfect, but after modification the image has another size, that I can't understand how to control.

I have added image with the same size as a container. Sizes = 320 x 524

There is an method in the sources that return cropping image:

```
- (UIImage *)deleteBackgroundOfImage:(UIImageView *)image
{
    NSArray *points = [self.croppingPath points];

    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
    rect.size = image.image.size;


    UIBezierPath *aPath;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0.0);
    {
        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(rect);
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];

        aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

        // Set the starting point of the shape.
        CGPoint p1 = [MZCroppableView convertCGPoint:[[points objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue] fromRect1:image.frame.size toRect2:image.image.size];
        [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(p1.x, p1.y)];

        for (uint i=1; i<points.count; i++)
        {
            CGPoint p = [MZCroppableView convertCGPoint:[[points objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue] fromRect1:image.frame.size toRect2:image.image.size];
            [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(p.x, p.y)];
        }
        [aPath closePath];
        [aPath fill];
    }

    UIImage *mask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);

    {
        CGContextClipToMask(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect, mask.CGImage);
        [image.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    }

    UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGRect croppedRect = aPath.bounds;
    croppedRect.origin.y = rect.size.height - CGRectGetMaxY(aPath.bounds);//This because mask become inverse of the actual image;

    croppedRect.origin.x = croppedRect.origin.x*2;
    croppedRect.origin.y = croppedRect.origin.y*2;
    croppedRect.size.width = croppedRect.size.width*2;
    croppedRect.size.height = croppedRect.size.height*2;

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(maskedImage.CGImage, croppedRect);

    maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    return maskedImage;
}
```

When I debug maskedImage before `maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];` line it seems the method remove background correct, but by some reason after the method `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(maskedImage.CGImage, croppedRect);` modify frame of cropped image. I tried to set cropped rect manually in CGImageCreateWithImageInRect to crop just needed frame.

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(maskedImage.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100));

But it return nothing for me.

How can I extract appropriate rect?

Also this lines multiply rect x2:

```
    croppedRect.origin.x = croppedRect.origin.x*2;
    croppedRect.origin.y = croppedRect.origin.y*2;
    croppedRect.size.width = croppedRect.size.width*2;
    croppedRect.size.height = croppedRect.size.height*2;
```

So when I debug it:

origin=(x=242, y=874) size=(width=191, height=164)

So as you can see the Y point out of my image height size 524, but by some reason it works.